# Is a convergent subsuccession of the union of two convergent successions a subsuccession of one of the two?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be real valued successions such that $a_n \longrightarrow A \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b_n \longrightarrow B \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $\{c_n\} = \{a_n\} \cup \{b_n\}$. If $\{y_n\} \subset \{c_n\}$ such that $y_n$ converges to some real value, is it true that there is an $\{x_n\} \subset \{y_n\}$ such that $\{x_n\} \subset \{a_n\}$ or $\{x_n\} \subset \{b_n\}$?

Comment: The answer is yes, if $A \neq B$, no, if $A=B$.